# Is there a way to add missing version constraints in Gemfile automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I have many lines in my Gemfile that don't have a version constraint specified. Is there a way to automatically add any missing ones based on what is currently installed?

Comment: If you did that, you'd be duplicating the job of `Gemfile.lock`. Version upgrades _will_ become multi-hour jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the output from `bundle list` to make things a lot quicker, but there's nothing totally automated.

For details on what version constraints to use, check out Thoughtbot's [blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-healthy-bundle) on adding version constraints to Gemfiles, and their [Ruby best practice guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices#bundler).